# How can I setup a TLS/SSL connection using openssl

Tags: ssl, authentication, openssl

Let's say I have PC A and PC B.
Assuming both have certificates signed by a CA.
How can I do mutual authentication here using openssl. What are the commands I have to use ? Brief explanation with some commands will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to simply connect to PC using `openssl` you have to use `openssl s_server` on one side and `openssl s_client` on another side:

```
PCA> openssl s_server -cert ./server.crt -key ./server.key -accept 8443
PCB> openssl s_client -connect PCA:8443
```

And if you really want mutual authentication here using openssl, you should add verification checks for openssl:

```
PCA> openssl s_server -cert ./server.crt -key ./server.key -accept 8443 -Verify on -verify_return_error
PCB> openssl s_client -connect PCA:8443 -cert ./client.crt -key ./client.key -verify on -verify_return_error
```

so both sides will drop connection in case of there are problems with certificates.

Comment: thanks, I exactly need this. I will try it out and mark this as accepted. Just one question, Don't I have to `-CAfile ca_cert.crt` also to validate the certificate is signed by correct CA ?

Comment: Simply: yes, you have to use `-CAfile ca_cert.crt`.But also you should use `-crl_check` to check certificates for revocation. In more details: there are number of options: you may use `-CApath` or `SSL_CERT_DIR` and `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variables. Or place your CA to `cert.pem` file under `openssl version -a | grep DIR` directory. Just choose any way you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to either A or B using openssl you could use something like:

```
openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:443
```

or more verbose (printing the certs)

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect x.x.x.x:443
```

Where x.x.x.x is the IP or host.